# Android: .getDrawable deprecated

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter, cardview

Изучаю Android менее месяца по книжке Head First Android. Столкнулся с проблемой, перерыл Stackoverflow, gitHub, не могу найти ответ. Как заменить устаревший метод .getDrawable таким образом, чтобы получить из CardView значение для Drawable? Если использовать ContextCompat, то что подставлять в виде context?

```
package com.example.android.bitsandpizzas;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CaptionedImagesAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CaptionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private String[] captions;
private int[] imageIds;

public CaptionedImagesAdapter(String[] captions, int[] imageIds) {
    this.captions = captions;
    this.imageIds = imageIds;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CardView cardView;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
    }
}

@Override
public CaptionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_captioned_image, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(cv);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
    Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(drawable);
    imageView.setContentDescription(captions[position]);
    TextView textView = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
    textView.setText(captions[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return captions.length;
}
```

}

Проблема здесь:

```
'Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position]);'
```

ContextCompat не знаю как применить:

```
 'Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context<?>, imageIds[position]);
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: А почему не `imageView.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);` ? Или можно взять контекст у любой вью `Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(cardView.getContext(), imageIds[position]);`

Comment: При использовании Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(cardView.getContext(), imageIds[position]); выдается ошибка, подчеркивается аргумент imageView.setImageResource(drawable); Ошибка: SetImageResource(int) in ImageView cannot be applied to (android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(drawable); заменил на  imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable); код компилируется. Видимо, эта проблема решена. Но приложение все равно завершается с ошибкой))) Буду искать дебаггером где. Спасибо

Comment: Debugger выявил NullPointerException (картинка).

Comment: 'public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(cardView.getContext(), imageIds[position]);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        imageView.setContentDescription(captions[position]);
        TextView textView = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        textView.setText(captions[position]);'

Comment: @woesss где собака зарыта?

Comment: Вы неправильно реализуете холдер. Все нужные Вам вью следует объявить его полями и **проинициализировать** их в конструкторе или в `onCreateViewHolder`, а в `onBindViewHolder` только вставлять в них данные (тексты, картинки, ...). У Вас `NPE` потому что полю `cardView` не присвоено никакого значения.

Comment: @woesss, Про порядок инициализации и заполнения данными я разобрался. Все оказалось банально просто. Я был невнимателен и не проинициализировал cardView в классе ViewHolder  и указал неверный параметр в сигнатуре конструктора. Все работает! Правильный код:       public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CardView cardView;
        public ViewHolder( **CardView** v) {
            super(v);
            **cardView = v;** 
        }